Probability of SSRW being nonnegative, conditioning on returning to zero at a certain time
Question: suppose $\{X_n\}$ is a simple symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$, compute
$$P(\min_{0\leq m\leq 2n}X_m = 0 | X_{2n}=0)$$
My only idea was that by the symmetric nature of the process, suppose there was $k$ total return to $0$, then the probability of the process being nonnegative would be $2^{-k}$. However I don't know how to compute probabilities related to $k$ given a return at $2n$. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

I presume $X_0=0$.

This is the conditional probability of SSRW never hitting negative axes conditioned on $X_{2n}=0$. First of all,
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{2n}=0)=\binom{2n}{n}2^{-2n}.
$$
Next, we want to compute the joint probability
$$
(*)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\ge 0, X_2\ge0,\dots, X_{2n-1}\ge 0, X_{2n}=0)
$$
which equals (assume that you start at time $-1$ and move ups the first step)
\begin{align}
(*)&=2\mathbb{P}(X_1\ge 1, X_2\ge1,\dots, X_{2n}\ge 1, X_{2n+1}=1)
\\ &=4\mathbb{P}(X_1\ge 1,\dots, X_{2n}\ge 1, X_{2n+1}\ge 1, X_{2n+2}=0)
\\ &=4\mathbb{P}(\text{all }X_i\ge 1,\text{first visit to $0$ at time $2n+2$})
\end{align}
The probability that the first return to the origin occurs at epoch $2n+2$, which, according to Feller Volume 1 pages 77-78 equals
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\text{first visit to $0$ at time $2n+2$})
&=
\mathbb{P}(X_1\ne 0,X_2\ne0,\dots,X_{2n+1}\ne 0,X_{2n}=0)
\\ &
=\frac{u_{2(n+1)}}{2n+1}=\frac1{2n+1}\binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}2^{-2(n+1)}
\end{align}
and by symmetry
$$
\mathbb{P}(\text{all }X_i\ge 1,\text{first visit to $0$ at time $2n+2$})=\frac12\mathbb{P}(\text{first visit to $0$ at time $2n+2$})
$$
so
$$
(*)=\frac12\cdot 4\cdot \frac1{2n+1}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}2^{-2(n+1)}.
$$
Hence the conditional probability equals
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_1\ge 0,\dots,X_{2n-1}\ge 0,X_{2n}=0)}
{\mathbb{P}(X_{2n}=0)}&=\frac{\frac2{2n+1}\binom{2n+2}{n+1}2^{-2(n+1)}}{\binom{2n}{n}2^{-2n}}
\\
&=\frac1{n+1}.
\end{align}

This took me a few moments to understand..But I think I get it. Very ingenious.

Yes, I know it's not easy. There's quite a lot on these type of questions in Feller Volume 1, Chapter III.
